# What are useful websites for scouting GIS related jobs?

Tags: career

What are useful websites for scouting GIS related jobs?

Comment: Let's please provide *reasons* and *evidence* to support the answers.  Otherwise this thread should be closed as potentially subjective and argumentative.

Comment: I feel obligated to put in a word for our sponsor :) http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=gis&location=

Comment: whuber is correct, **in order for this thread to remain viable, the recommendations must have supporting commentary and evidence as to why you are recommended the site. I *will* delete answers which do not have this, starting tomorrow.**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
>   because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
>   and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
>   should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
>   type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
>   site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
>   to do so by editing this answer.

---

[GIS Jobs Clearinghouse](http://www.gjc.org/) is a great site for both posting and finding Geospatial related jobs.  I have used it to fill my last three vacancies.  You don't need to create an account to search the jobs which is a big bonus.  They even have an option to display job postings via a map as well as a twitter account announcing new postings.

Answer (score 9):

This isn't GIS specific, but [dice.com](http://www.dice.com) is a pretty good resource for the US. Especially if you are looking for something a little more technical (not just map production, but something that uses analysis or programming skills). When I would receive calls for a job that I hadn't directly applied for, I would ask where they found my resume and Dice had the most hits.

From my experience when I was job hunting last year, many of the jobs on GIS Clearinghouse and GIS Jobs were out of date.

Answer (score 7):

I've found [indeed.com](http://indeed.com) to be pretty good, I always find the greatest number of postings there.  They seem to be the Google of job searches, with jobs from many obscure sites coming up in the results.  You can narrow the search by state and can sort by greatest relevance or newest postings.

Answer (score 6):

For french people or others willing to speak french (and mostly work in france) a well-known site is http://georezo.net/forum/viewforum.php?id=10. Sorry for others! ;-)

The *Georezo* is a non profit organization of volunteers which aims to provide support and gather resources from and for the *french GIS small world*. It provides community tools like bibliography, forums, blogs, ... and gather job ads from private companies and government/public sector.

Answer (score 6):

UK GIS and Cartographic Jobs:

A Free List for GIS and Cartographic Jobs in the United Kingdom

https://www.jiscmail.ac.uk/cgi-bin/webadmin?A0=gis-jobs

Updated hourly and for UK users a valuable and active source of part-time, contract and permanent GIS centric Jobs.

[Jobsite for the UK](http://www.jobsite.co.uk/cgi-bin/advsearch?search_type=quick&location_within=20&fp_skill_include=gis&location_include=&search_salary_type=A&search_salary_low=ANY&jobtype=E&daysback=7) (the completed search for "GIS")

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the GIS-specific sites already mentioned, I had good success finding job advertisements when searching with the following non-GIS specific sites:

1. [LinkedIn.com](http://www.LinkedIn.com/)- In my experience, most jobs offers are given to people who know someone within the company already and have an "inside referral".  LinkedIn is a good way to keep up with those contacts.
2. [SimplyHired.com](http://www.simplyhired.com/)- Very similar to Indeed.com, but I found with the right search criteria it provided very good results and scraped job advertisements from many other sites that did not come up in typical searches.
3. [CareerBuilder.com](http://www.careerbuilder.com/)- I had quite a few recruiters contacting me through CareerBuilders after I posted my resume for public review.

I would also recommend getting involved in your local GIS user groups as a way of connecting with potential employers.  Many have email lists that they advertise job announcements through.  Personal relationships go a long way in getting hired, often being just as important as the skills you have.

Answer (score 3):

[Digital-Geography.com joblist](http://www.digital-geography.com/jobs-digital-geoscientists/) - mostly for German speaking countries.

This list is a nice starting point if you're looking for a GIS (related) job in a German speaking country. It is updated weekly and curated by Riccardo. The job listings there are a mix of him scouring over job mailing-lists and employers sending in job offers themselves.

Answer (score 0):

[My GIS Jobs](http://www.mygisjobs.com) - They seem to have 7 or 8 new GIS job listings added each day - primarily US-based jobs.